# NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'topics' with arguments '(3,)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['topics/$']

Tags: python, django

My question is about redirection again to a /topics/[id_number_for_topic] page where all entries for topic are located. When I end an entry editing in /edit_entry/[id_number_for_entry] and click the button the error is occured as below:

```
Reverse for 'topics' with arguments '(3,)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['topics/$']
```

This number 3 indicates for a topic id.

I guess the problem is with return instruction in views.py > edit_entry() or in regex expression

My code:

**views.py**

```
def edit_entry(request, entry_id):
    """Edycja wpisu"""
    entry = Entry.objects.get(id=entry_id)
    topic = entry.topic
    if request.method != 'POST':
        form = EntryForm(instance=entry)
    else:
        form = EntryForm(instance=entry, data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('learning_logs:topics',
                                                args=[topic.id]))
    context = {'entry': entry, 'topic': topic, 'form': form}
    return render(request, 'edit_entry.html', context)
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^topics/(?P<topic_id>\d+)/$', views.topic, name='topic'),
url(r'^edit_entry/(?P<entry_id>\d+)/$', views.edit_entry, name='edit_entry'),
```

**models.py**

```
class Topic(models.Model):
    """Temat poznawany przez usera"""
    text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        """Zwraca reprezentacje modelu w postaci ciagu text."""
        return self.text


class Entry(models.Model):
    """Konkret informacje o postepie w nauce"""
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic)
    text = models.TextField()
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'entries'

        def __str__(self):
            return self.text[:50] + "..."
```

**edit_entry.html**

```
{% block content %}
<p><a href="{% url 'learning_logs:topic' topic.id %}">{{ topic }}</a></p>
<h3>Edycja wpisu:</h3>
<form action="{% url 'learning_logs:edit_entry' entry.id %}" method='post'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button name="submit">Zapisz zmiany</button>
</form>
{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo in this code. Here:

```
 return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('learning_logs:topics',
                                            args=[topic.id]))
```

Should be:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('learning_logs:topic',
                                            args=[topic.id]))
```

Comment: Great, please [accept this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as correct :)

Answer (score 0):

I advice you to use `reverse` from `django`.

```
from django.urls import reverse
...
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('learning_logs:topics', kwargs=dict(topic_id=topic.id)))
```